# Why do we include dates within single quotes in sql server while inserting?

Tags: sql-server

insert into mytable values(1,**'06-06-2012'**);

why do we include date within single quotes here?!! However, we do not do the same while passing the value through  **parameterized** query?!!

Comment: May be you need to talk with Microsoft

Comment: Question: Who/what is the audience for whom you write code? Answer: The compiler. If you need a date or string literal, the grammar that the compiler understands is that it starts and ends with a single quote. A parameter starts with a @ sign, so the compiler knows that it references a place in memory, and not a date or string literal. It's all about grammar and what the compiler understands.

Answer (score 3):

With literals, the SQL Server database engine parses the value into native format during query execution.  The datetime value is parsed into an 8-byte native binary representation.

Parameter values are passed to SQL Server in native binary format so enclosurse are not used.  The client API converts the parameter value according to the declared parameter data type and passes the binary value to SQL Server using a TDS protocol remote procedure call.  SQL Server doesn't need to parse the value at all, although conversion might still be needed if the parameter data type doesn't match the data type needed in the query.

For example, if you pass a string parameter value of '06-12-2014' for a table data type of datetime, SQL Server will convert the parameter string value to datetime according to the session `DATEFORMAT` setting (could be interpreted as '2014-06-12' or '2014-12-06.  Passing a native datetime parameter avoids the ambiguous date format because the task of converting the value to the native binary value was already done on the client.